# How to link description field (HTML) with the information in Database?

Tags: php, html, database, blob

I am building a site where users can upload their images and type in image descriptions. Then on another page I am displaying image and a field where the image description should be.
And I have few questions in relation with this.

1. What is the best way to "fetch" the description field from the DB?
2. Whats the best way to link the image and the description? the way that when image A1 is displayed (fetched) the description A1 will be displayed with it in its own field?

Many thanks in advance!
Sau

PS.
I am using PHP and PHPMyAdmin

Comment: 1. With a SQL SELECT query. 2. Store both in the same sql table next to each other (i.e. in different columns) so that one row of data in the table will contain both pieces of matching data.

Comment: It's worth asking, are you storing the image as a Base64 IN the database, or are you saving a physical file?  If physical file, you'll need the `file path` "next" to the description in the database as Adyson mentioned.

Comment: At the moment I am saving images in the path (folder) but I was planning on storing them either in mysql or elsewhere (what is your recommendation on this? if the amount of uploads gets larger then I want to keep it on some separate server not in mysql)